# Updating fields after SubmitChanges in C# using foreach loops

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a project that I am working on, which is related to the work of daily shifts for employees, so that I have made the code for filling in the dates and their days in the relevant table `ResultTB` as follows and it's work correctly

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text);
var dt2 = DateTime.Parse(txtToDate.Text);

var dt = DateTime.Parse(txtFromDate.Text);

if (dt <= dt2)
{
    dt = dt.AddDays(-1);

    while (dt2 >= dt1)
    {
        List<ResultTB> ResultList = new List<ResultTB>
                    {
                        new ResultTB{NameOfDay = dt1.DayOfWeek.ToString(),DateOfDay = dt=dt.AddDays(1) }
                    };

        foreach (var item in ResultList)
        {
            dt1 = dt1.AddDays(1);
            db.ResultTBs.InsertOnSubmit(item);
        }

        db.SubmitChanges();

        DGVResult.DataSource = db.ResultTBs.ToList();
    }
}
```

Now I would like to make an update to the table `ResultTB` to columns `EmpName`+`EmpID` from `EmployeeTB`, so that the code searches in the table `EmployeeTB` which have the status of the employee “possible” and assigns it to a date in order, and this is the code that I wrote, but it adds the first person in the `EmployeeTB` table and assigns it to all the dates in the table `ResultTB`.

```
var EmpList = db.EmployeeTBs
                .Where(x => x.EmpStatus == "possible").ToList();

foreach (var EmpItem in EmpList)
{
    var ListOfResult = db.ResultTBs.Where(r => r.EmpName == null).ToList();

    foreach (var itemResult in ListOfResult)
    {
        itemResult.EmpID = EmpItem.EmpID;
        itemResult.EmpName = EmpItem.EmpName;
    }

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I tried many solutions but it didn't work with me please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Change db to EmpItem :  var ListOfResult = EmpItem.ResultTBs.Where(r => r.EmpName == null).ToList();

Comment: thanks for your comment, i have tried to do like your code but i got an error in : ReultTBs

Comment: Try instead of null use string.Empty

Comment: not working also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var EmpList = db.EmployeeTBs.Where(x => x.EmpStatus == "possible").ToList();

for (int i=0; i< EmpList.length; i++)
{
    var ListOfResult = db.ResultTBs.Where(r => r.EmpName == null).ToList();

    ListOfResult[i].EmpID = EmpList[i].EmpID
    ListOfResult[i].EmpName = EmpList[i].EmpName
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

If I understood your question correctly this should work.

Comment: Could you please explain by writing the correct code? Thank you

Comment: I edited my answer but I'm not exactly sure of what you want to do. Could you post a sample of the expected result?

Comment: Thank you mr.Muhammad you give me the correct Answer , that's what i'm looking for